# Transparent Texture With OpenGL-ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to add a transparent texture on top a cube. Only the front face is not transparent. Other sides are transparent. What could be the problem?. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT : I found that the face which is drawn first is opaque.

3 face of the cube is drawn.

Opaque face.((This face's index is given first in GLdrawElements))
[image: opaque]

Transparent face.
[image: tranparent]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably ran into a sorting problem. To display transparent geometries correctly the faces of the object have to be sorted from back to front.

Unfortunately there is no built-in support for that in opengl-es (or in any gfx-library in existance). The only possibility is to sort your polygons, recreate your object each frame and draw it with correctly ordered faces.

A workaround would be using additive transparency instead of normal transparency. Additive transparency is an order independent calculation. You have to remember to turn off z-buffer writes while drawing because otherwise some geometry may be ocluded.

Additive transparency is achieved by setting both blendfunc values to GL_ONE.

Comment: i don't have a transparent hierarchy. Opacity of the polygons are same.My problem is with the texture. I have transparent .png . Which is opaque for the first drawn surface of the cube. I have also cleared the CGcontext .

Comment: could you upload a screenshot somewhere? maybe that could help finding the problem.

Comment: i have uploaded the image!. The red side is opaque.The red polygon is drawn first. if i draw the yellow face first it becomes opaque.

Comment: 1. I corrected a mistake, i meant back to front, not front to back. 2. That pretty much looks like the problem i described. The first face you draw is blended with the black background and then looks opaque. If that face is indeed the face that is farest away, everything looks ok, until you rotate the cube. Then the first face is drawn "opaque" (it's not blended with anything on the screen) and the others are hidden behind that face because of z-buffer clipping.

Comment: Ya You were absolutely correct!. I misunderstood. Thanks a lot!.